# Why is std::move unnecessary in this coroutine-related example?

Tags: c++, c++20, move-semantics, c++-coroutine

In Josuttis' C++20 book there's a little section at the end of §14.2.7 where a coroutine return type supporting move semantics is shown:

```cpp
class CoroTask {
  …
 public:
  struct primise_type;
  using CoroHdl = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
 private:
  CoroHdl hdl;
 public:
  …
  // support move semantics:
  CoroTask(CoroTask&& c) noexcept
   : hdl{std::move(c.hdl)} {
    c.hdl = nullptr;
  }
  CoroTask& operator=(CoroTask&& c) noexcept {
    if (this != &c) {         // if no self-assignment
      if (hdl) {
        hdl.destroy();        // - destroy old handle (if there is one)
      }
      hdl = std::move(c.hdl); // - move handle
      c.hdl = nullptr;        // - moved-from object has no handle anymore
  }
  return *this;
};
```

and the comment is made that `std::move`, strictly speaking, is redundant. Why is that? (Leaving aside that I would have expected to see `std::move(c).hdl` rather than `std::move(c.hdl)`, as `c` is the argument with r-value reference type.)

Comment: It looks like you are "moving" a pointer, which in this case will just be copying it

Comment: ^ agreed.  We really need to see the type involved to know for certain.

Comment: And if that is indeed the case, *both* `std::move`s are redundant...

Comment: Assuming `hdl` is a pointer, `: hdl{std::exchange(c.hdl, nullptr)} {`

Comment: It would help if you included a complete example. Presumably `hdl` is a `std::coroutine_handle`?

Comment: @Barry, yes it is.

Comment: @PaulSanders, yes, I think the comment targets both of those.

Comment: @Eljay, `std::exchange` uses `std::move` and `std::forward` anyway.

Comment: @Alex, I've updated the snippet. `c.hdl` is not  a pointer, but a `std::coroutine_handle`.

Comment: `std::coroutine_handle` is a LiteralType, which means it is very simple (like an `int`). Generally those get no benefit from moving as moving those is a copy.  Moving only benefits things like `std::vector` when you point to the data and when you do a move you just swap the pointers instead of doing a new allocation and a copy.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I guess the "generally" refers to the fact that a literal type _can_ be move-only, hence one needs to `std::move`, even if not for performance?

Comment: @Enlico Yes. That's the only case I can think of where you might have to move a literal type.